# Firefox/IE CSS Issue - Image not scaling to percentage

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm using a 3rd party full-screen slider on the homepage of this website.  The images inside each slide are set to be no larger than 75% width, and it seems to work in Safari and Chrome, but not in IE (11) or Firefox.

Any ideas what's going on with this one?

http://www.communitychurchbunnell.com

Comment: So the if the width is 1000px the height should be no more than 750px? I'm a bit confused.  And by third party tool you mean jQuery or what tool?

Comment: Please link to a demo that will not change; live sites change too frequently to be linked in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Here's a version where the slides don't change Jonathan : http://demo.communitychurchbunnell.com

Comment: Craig - I just mean that the image should not be wider than the screen size. Normally I set max-width to 100%, but in this case used 75% to try and trouble shoot what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your width to make it work with IE

```
#main-content #fullpage .section img, #main-content #fullpage .slide img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 75% !important;
}
```

Also, !important is not necessary.

**EDIT**

the .fp-tableCell div is being set to the width of the image within.
In the file jquery.fullpage.min.js add max-width:100vh to fix the problem:

```
.fp-tableCell {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: I only added the !important to try and get it to work because it wasn't catching for some reason.  I can try 100%, but I don't want all images to be 100% width, I just don't want them to be larger than 100% (I want them responsive).  The plugin I'm using uses table and table-cell display types to vertically center things which I suspect may be the culprit.  I'm not sure though as I've never really use those types.  Odd that the rendering problem is only IE/Firefox.

Comment: You must add the width for the max-width to work.  If you add width 100% it will not make all the images 100% width.  It will make them 75% of the width of the containing div.  In IE the max-width property does not work with out width being initially set, I guess this may be the case for some versions of Firefox too.

Comment: I had never heard of that being the case (width needs to be specified for max-width to work), but I added it and it works.  So how to you keep images from stretching beyond their natural size.  Your solution works for some images with are "slides" and are really large, but on the next to the last slide (the Awana image), as you would expect the image is stretched to 100%, when it shouldn't be.  It should remain it's normal size and only shrink (via max-width) when the viewport resizes : http://demo.communitychurchbunnell.com/

Comment: But because we have to add the 100% for it to work in FF and IE, it stretches the image (as expected).  I've never come across this before, how do you get around it?

Comment: I believe width:auto; is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.  Almost the same as when you try to animate a height property with css, you have to have an actual value, "auto" doesn't work.  Very strange, like I said never seen this before.  Must be because the containing element is set as display:table-cell

Comment: I'll look into it further.  Can you stop the page from automatically scrolling?  I'll be able to debug it faster.

Comment: Yes, you can view a non-scrolling version here : http://demo.communitychurchbunnell.com/

Comment: I have added and edit to the first answer.  You need to add min-width to your jquery.fullpage.min.css, see answer above.

Comment: I thought for a moment that you had a typo because I hadn't heard of these new vw and vh units.  Because I thought you had a typo I tried adding max-width:100% and it obviously didn't work. Found out it seems to be an issue with FF/IE and max-width inside of table cells. Adding "table-layout:fixed;" to the element that was set as "display:table;" fixed my issue.  After I did some more searching and read about vm and vh I went back and tried your solution again which of course worked - so I've actually implemented both.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly there seems to be an issue with max-width on images inside tables/cells in FF and IE (haven't tested others), but the way I ended up fixing this issue was adding table-layout:fixed; to the element that was set as display:table